# How to build easyui layout with multiple nested layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-easyui

I have used easyui nested layout in my app. I refered the below code as given in  the easyui demo.

```
<div class="easyui-layout" style="width:700px;height:350px;">
        <div data-options="region:'north'" style="height:50px"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'south',split:true" style="height:50px;"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'east',split:true" title="East" style="width:180px;"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="West" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'center',iconCls:'icon-ok'" title="Center">
            <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true">
                <div data-options="region:'north',split:true,border:false" style="height:50px"></div>
                <div data-options="region:'west',split:true,border:false" style="width:100px"></div>
                <div data-options="region:'center',border:false"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

The demo link is

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Layout&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

I need to use multiple inner layouts  like this.

```
<div class="easyui-layout" style="width:700px;height:350px;">
         <div data-options="region:'north'" style="height:50px"></div>
         <div data-options="region:'south',split:true" style="height:50px;"></div>
         <div data-options="region:'east',split:true" title="East" style="width:180px;"></div>
         <div data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="West" style="width:100px;"></div>
         <div data-options="region:'center',iconCls:'icon-ok'" title="Center">
             <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true" id="innerlayout1">
                 <div data-options="region:'north',split:true,border:false" style="height:50px"></div>
                 <div data-options="region:'west',split:true,border:false" style="width:100px"></div>
                 <div data-options="region:'center',border:false"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true" id="innerlayout2" style="display:none;">
                          <div data-options="region:'north',split:true,border:false" style="height:50px"></div>
                          <div data-options="region:'west',split:true,border:false" style="width:100px"></div>
                          <div data-options="region:'center',border:false"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true" id="innerlayout3" style="display:none;">
                          <div data-options="region:'north',split:true,border:false" style="height:50px"></div>
                          <div data-options="region:'west',split:true,border:false" style="width:100px"></div>
                          <div data-options="region:'center',border:false"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

The first innerlayout is visible by default and for this east region has to be in expanded condition. And when another innerlayout is made visible , the other inner layouts are hidden and east region is collapsed. My problem is when east region is collapsed there occurs a white space between centre and east regions. I want the centre region to get enlarged so that the space wont come.

Sorry for my poor English. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you are trying to do, you need to first split the center into west, center, east and then split each of those into north, west, and center:

```
<div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true";">
        <div data-options="region:'north',split:true" style="height:50px"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'south',split:true" style="height:50px;"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'east',split:true" title="East" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="West" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div data-options="region:'center', split:true">
            <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true">
                <div data-options="region:'east',split:true" style="width:250px">
                     <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true">
                        <div data-options="region:'north',split:true" Title="Center East" style="height:150px"></div>
                        <div data-options="region:'west',split:true"  style="width:125px;"></div>
                        <div data-options="region:'center',split:true"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-options="region:'west',split:true" style="width:250px">
                    <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true">
                        <div data-options="region:'north',split:true" Title="Center West" style="height:150px"></div>
                        <div data-options="region:'west',split:true"  style="width:125px;"></div>
                        <div data-options="region:'center',split:true"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-options="region:'center',split:true" >
                   <div class="easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true">
                        <div data-options="region:'north',split:true" Title="Center Center" style="height:150px"></div>
                        <div data-options="region:'west',split:true"  style="width:125px;"></div>
                        <div data-options="region:'center',split:true"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

result: 
[image]